# Is there a way to lock a folder's icon without making its contents Read Only?

Tags: icon, finder

I have a network share that is used by a large group of kids. They love changing the icon of this folder, which causes a lot of debate. I know that there is a hidden file that specifies the icon; can I lock this file so the icon of the folder can't be changed anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're exactly right. Here's how to lock the file that controls the icon:

[Show hidden files.](http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2008/04/show-hidden-files.html)

Navigate to your folder.

There will be a file called `Icon` inside it.

Go to the Get Info window for that file and check the Locked checkbox.

Try to change the icon. You can't. Ta-da.

Comment: Thanks! For a volume's icon it looks like the file is called .VolumeIcon.icn rather than Icon, but other than that it works exactly like you said.